# How to integrate a remote VM server with all VMs to on-site LAN

Tags: vpn, virtual-machines, local-area-network

I have two sites: 1. the "local" site with client machines only and 2. the "remote" site with one VM server (ubuntu) hosting a number of VMs (ubuntu / windows).

Currently I'm connecting to those VMs using SSH tunnelling, but this is tedious (lots of fragile tunnels to maintain) and doesn't allow me to use standard ports for common services.

I'd like to connect to those hosted VMs like they were physical machines connected to the "local" LAN.

I've searched around, but I haven't found any questions dealing with connecting to hosted VM NAT network. All questions dealt with physical LANs and my networking knowledge really isn't sufficient to translate physical to VM NAT.

Is this possible? If so, what do I need to do to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I would configure an IPSec site to site VPN for this using something like [strongSwan](https://www.strongswan.org/). It should be fairly straightforward and the strongwan site has [configuration examples](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/IKEv2Examples) to work with.

Comment: This is the approach I was thinking to use. However, I have no idea on how to bind VPN software to VirtualBox's VM NAT Network